# Assigning Final Scores to Identified Technologies: Considering Users' StackOverflow Reputation, badge counts, post scores, no.of posts, and post date

Tags: tags, data-science, weighted, scoring

I am trying to determine the importance of various factors in assigning a score for identified technologies using the user's StackOverflow post tags and content.

The considering factors are users' reputation scores, badge counts(gold, silver, bronze), post scores, number of posts, and post date. I want to give more weight to technologies identified from recent posts and give higher weight to users who have earned gold badges.

I have already identified technologies using post tags and titles, but I am having trouble assigning appropriate weights to each factor for calculating the final score for the technology expertise score. Can you suggest a way for me to assign a final score to identified technologies without assigning specific weights as I like to each factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there's this thing called the Analytical Hierarchy Process (AHP) created by Saaty in the 70s. It's like a fancy decision-making method that helps deal with tricky problems. You know, those decisions with lots of factors... AHP helps you sort them out.

Here's how it works: First, you break down the problem into smaller parts, like categories and subcategories. This helps keep things organized. Then comes the cool part: you compare these parts to figure out which ones are more important than others. You give them scores like "equal importance" or "way more important."

To gather these scores, we made a Google Form where people say what's more important. We put all their answers in a Google Sheet, and whichever score gets the most votes wins. We do this for every part, so we know what matters most.

Then, we use math to figure out the real weight of each part. It's like a balancing act. Imagine a seesaw with weights on it. The heavier side is the one that matters more. We do this for categories and subcategories, using equations and stuff.

After all that math, we have these weights that show what really counts. We even break down subcategories like "Badge Count" into smaller pieces like gold, silver, and bronze badges.

So, in the end, AHP gives us a clear way to see what's important and what's not.  This helps us make smart choices and pick the most crucial factors in any decision.